# Displaying multiple data in DetailView of yii2 by using the same id

Tags: yii2

I have a small problem to display multiple data in detailview of `yii2`.

Let me explain the problem.

[image]

This is my search page. Here I have 2 books with same `book_id=1`. Now, while I am viewing the detail of this record in the view page, I need to display both books' numbers. `Acc no` is the book number.

Below is my view page:

[image]

This is my view page. Now, in `Acc No` there is only one book number `22478` but `22479` is not displaying.

Let me show you the code of my gridview.

```
 <?= DetailView::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'attributes' => [
        'id',
        'book_id',
        'accession_no',
        [
        'format'=>'raw',
        'attribute'=>'title',
        ]

        [
        'format'=>'raw',
        'attribute'=>'title',

        'value' => $model1->language == 1 ? 
        "<p class='n'>" . $model1->title . "</p>" 
         : $model1->title,
       ],

        [
                'format' => 'raw',
                'attribute' => 'qty',


                 'value' => $model1->book_qty,
            ],
  ],
            ]) ?>
```

I need help as I am new to coding.

Comment: DetailView is for an instance only  .. if you need  more then a result you shoud use others widget like gridview of listview  .. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-widgets.html

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-widgets.html#detailview

> **DetailView displays the detail of a single data $model.**
>
> DetailView is best used for displaying a model in a regular format (e.g. each
> model attribute is displayed as a row in a table.) The model can be
> either an instance of yii\base\Model or an associative array.

So basically what you are trying to do is not possible using DetailView.

You should try looking into using [Yii2 ListView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-widgets.html#listview) to solve your requirements.

Comment: can you solve my problem ?? i havent used list view yet. am bit confused

Comment: @BibashAdhikari it's not possible for anyone else to solve your problem..the community can only guide you in the right direction. :) Have you tried anything in regards to implementing the `ListView`? If yes, then share the code. What's your confusion about? Please be specific to get the proper guidance.